# Retrieve only one label from set of individuals with multiple labels

Tags: sparql, rdfs

Suppose I have the following set of individuals, where some of them have more than one `rdfs:label`:

| Individual | Label |
| --- | --- |
| ind_01 | "ind-001" |
| ind_02 | "ind-002" |
| ind_02 | "ind-2" |
| ind_03 | "label3" |
| ind_04 | "ind-4" |
| ind_04 | "ind-04" |
| ... | ... |

I would like to run a SPARQL query that retrieves only one label per individual, no matter which one (i.e., the choice can be totally arbitrary). Thus, a suitable output based on the above dataset would be:

| Individual | Label |
| --- | --- |
| ind_01 | "ind-001" |
| ind_02 | "ind-002" |
| ind_03 | "label3" |
| ind_04 | "ind-4" |
| ... | ... |

Comment: there is the `sample` aggregate function which you can use on each group which in your case is based on the individual URI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SAMPLE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#defn_aggSample), which "returns an arbitrary value from the multiset passed to it".

```
SELECT ?individual (SAMPLE(?label) AS ?label_sample) 
WHERE {
  ?individual rdfs:label ?label .
}
GROUP BY ?individual
```